# jQuery UI DatePicker theme

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui, datepicker

I was wondering if there is a way when using DatePicker to override any CSS from the page it's being displayed on and simply show a default plain theme. I just want a basic grey calendar but DatePicker appears to be picking up elements from my website. The code i'm using is as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>  
<script>
$(function(){
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });  
});  
</script>
```

I'm unable to upload a picture of my calendar (as I do not have enough reputation points) but basically where the Days of the week would be (M, T, W, T, F, S, S) the background is dark green and the text red. The spacing is also quite large above and below the days. I'm hoping there is a quick and simple way to format this in the code above.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"` is the theme you are using. Download a copy, and take a look in the file for `.datepicker`. You can find more here: http://jqueryui.com/themeroller/, download one that you like from the gallery and replace the `.datepicker` styles with the new ones that you want instead.

Answer (score 0):

Please add an empty class in your control which is intended to be date-picker and use that class in your jquery

```
<input type="text" class="dateinput"/>
```

inside script tag it should be written as 
    $(function(){
    $( '.dateinput' ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy' });
    });